# How do I solve $\iint\limits_{\Omega}|xy|\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The integral is:

$$\iint\limits_{\Omega}|xy|\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

$\Omega$ is given by the circle with radius $a$ and center in the zero of coordinat plane. I am confused what to do with mudule. And how many integration regions should I have? As it is module I guess I have to take $1/4$ of circle.

Comment: You are right, you can calculate just 1/4 of the integral, for $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$ and the multiply times 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is four times that over the portion of the disc $A$ in the first quadrant.
This is
$$4\int_A xy\,dx\,dy.$$
This is easily done via polar coordinates $x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$ giving
$$4\int_0^a\int_0^{\pi/2}(r\cos t)(r\sin t)r\,dt\,dr.$$